# does spark optimize the network traffic for broadcasted variables?

Tags: apache-spark

knowing that spark uses multiple executors per worker node and that each executor runs in its own JVM, I wonder how /if does spark optimize the network traffic for broadcasted variables. Hopefully it does one single download for each worker node and then sends the already serialized data to the executors on that particular node. The other option would be to download the broadcasted data each time an executor needs it (therefore having to download multiple times the same data on a particular node).

Comment: to whoever downvoted the question, would you mind explaining your downvote ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Spark does optimize broadcasting using torrent broadcasts. To quote [the source](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/0446363ef466922a42de019ca14fada62959c1f3/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/broadcast/TorrentBroadcast.scala#L38-L51)

> ```
> * A BitTorrent-like implementation of [[org.apache.spark.broadcast.Broadcast]].
> *
> * The mechanism is as follows:
> *
> * The driver divides the serialized object into small chunks and
> * stores those chunks in the BlockManager of the driver.
> *
> * On each executor, the executor first attempts to fetch the object from its BlockManager. If
> * it does not exist, it then uses remote fetches to fetch the small chunks from the driver and/or
> * other executors if available. Once it gets the chunks, it puts the chunks in its own
> * BlockManager, ready for other executors to fetch from.
> *
> * This prevents the driver from being the bottleneck in sending out multiple copies of the
> * broadcast data (one per executor).
> ```

In the past there was another broadcast implementation (HTTP broadcast), but it was removed completely in 2.0.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @user10976591, so am I right saying that there's only one block manager per each worker node ?