# how to program against both mutable and immutable Map?

Tags: scala

I want to write a function

```
def doSomething(m: Map[X, Y]): Z = ???
```

for some given types `X, Y, Z`.

The function will do the same thing for both `immutable.Map` and `mutable.Map`.

Is there any way I can write that?

Comment: Accept `scala.collection.Map[X, Y]` as argument?

Comment: @Andrey just add it as an answer

Comment: What's the point? If this comment "answered" your question, then you can just delete it to get rid of the downvotes, *before* there are any upvoted answers (you won't be able to delete the question if there are upvoted answers). While there is [Unsung Hero](https://serverfault.com/help/badges/84/unsung-hero), there is no special badge for getting stuck in [this situation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54392344/does-spark-optimize-the-network-traffic-for-broadcasted-variables).

Comment: @Andrey  I don't mind, and I still think it may help others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just declare the argument `m` to be of type `collection.Map[X, Y]`.

Here is a quick way to find out what the least upper bound of the two types is:

```
import collection._
def f(a: mutable.Map[Int, Int], b: immutable.Map[Int, Int]) = List(a, b).head
```

The REPL with tell you that the return type is `collection.Map[Int, Int]`.

Answer (score 1):

Both `immutable.Map` and `mutable.Map` extends `scala.collection.Map`.

```
package scala
package collection
trait Map[A, +B] extends Iterable[(A, B)] with GenMap[A, B] with MapLike[A, B, Map[A, B]] {
  def empty: Map[A, B] = Map.empty

  override def seq: Map[A, B] = this
}
```

looking above you will see this is a generic interface in Scala to describe a Map. therefore your function could be `def doSomething(m: scala.collection.Map[X, Y]): Z = ???`

you will still have majority of Map interface functions to use, however, those ones that's not shared between mutable and immutable won't be there.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, indeed it answers my question but I had to give the "answer mark" to Andrey because he answered first.